# Is there a utility to show total up/download quantity of a process

Tags: networking, traffic

In bash I can run `time $(curl -L ...|bash)` to find out the total *time* this script takes.  Is there a way to get similar total information about the up/download traffic it generated?

Note that nethogs does not do what I need - it shows the traffic rates from time to time. I'd like the cummulative total of the traffic in/out.

Comment: What do you mean by `from time to time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep the `nethogs` running.

You can change display modes by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>.
The first default mode is kbps, after pressing <kbd>M</kbd> few times you can get total bytes.

---

**Edit: added screenshots**

[image: KB/sec]
[image: Total MB]

Comment: I mean computers are discrete, so I couldn't say 'continuously' :)